# How do I store user event info using session in Flask without requiring a log-in?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, flask-session

Every tutorial I've seen involving session in Flask has a log-in. I DO NOT want a login.

Let's say I were making a game, and I wanted to record the wins/losses. Without logging in, I want the user's wins/losses to be recorded while they visit the web app.

Is this possible?

[EDIT]
I'm starting to think sessions isn't want I want after all. I only want the wins/loses to be recorded while they're playing in the active browser. So maybe I should just have a box that updates wins/loses after each game?

Comment: I tried to delete becuase I had no idea what I was talking about and was worred I would just confuse future coders looking for answers. So here's what I found instead: Just USE IT. Session is a client-side cookie that is unique to each user/browser. So, if you want to store their answer, do session['answer'] = "whatever". Also, if you want to store their id, do session['id'] = 9875. Now they will both be associated with one user. GG

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Flask sessions. By default it uses the Werkzeug's provided 'secure cookie' to maintain sessions. However having said that you cannot simply rely on this for your client session state. For eg. If the user clears browser cache and history this will be lost, or if the user opens in incognito or another browser this state will not be available.

here's just a snippet from my application where I use the session information.

```
from flask import (Blueprint, request, render_template, redirect, session,
               make_response, jsonify)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    .. do something..
    session['somestateiinfo'] = "some val"
    render_template()..

@app.route('/state', methods=['GET', 'POST']))
def nextpage():
    print "session info", session
```

Comment: I do not need scores to remain after the user leaves/closes the browser. Just to have the wins/losses recorded while they're on the web app.

I've looked at the Flask session, and I know that's the way to record wins/losses for a user/browser, but I'm not exactly sure how.

For example, in the session list you have above, the 'somestateinfo' key is usually the user's log-in ID. However, I would not want to require users to make a log-in, so what would I use to identify user's and their browser session instead?